# Javascript autofill script not working on twitter login

Tags: javascript, twitter

Hi I have below code which is working on almost every site,but it is not working on twitter login.I have made a chorome extension which include this code.Please tell me what i have to edit in this code.

In this code first i will search password field and set password, and the above textfield will be username field.

I have also seperately tried to find  all password fields on twitter and setted to some value.But Its not working.

```
var data = {};

data['username']='*****' ;
data['password']='*****' ;

login(data);

function login(data)
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

   // var user=null;
    var username_index=null;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1)
     {
        if(inputs[i].type == 'password'&&inputs[i].style.display != "none" )
        {               
            inputs[i].placeholder="";
            inputs[i].value=data['password'];
            username_index=i-1;
            break;
        }
       /* if(inputs[i].type == 'text' || inputs[i].type == 'email' || inputs[i].type == 'number' )
        {
            user =inputs[i] ;
        }
        */
     }

    while(username_index>=0)
    {
        if(inputs[username_index].type == 'text' || inputs[username_index].type == 'email' || inputs[username_index].type == 'number'&&inputs[username_index].style.display != "none")
        {

            inputs[username_index].placeholder="";
        inputs[username_index].value=data['username'];
        i
        break;
       }

       username_index--;
   }


}
```

Comment: look at mitro login manager :)

Comment: i've look at mitro manager,but i want to know the technique to set my username into twitter login form using javascript .I have tested my code on many sites and its working fine.But its not working on twitter and some other sites.whether twitter had implemented some kind of security to avoid autofill using javascript.